# Destructuring while iterating through a Vec<Enum(String)>

Tags: rust

I have an enum called `Token` (can you guess what I'm trying to build? :P)

It looks an awful lot like this:

```
enum Token {
    Paren(String),
    Number(String),
    Name(String),
}
```

Now, I have a function with the following signature:

`fn tokenizer(input: String) -> Vec<Token>`

I have no reason to believe it's not basically working, so I obviously have a `Vec<Token>`.

Now, in my main function I have this:

```
let tokens = tokenizer("(add 44 5)".to_owned());
```

and I'd like to do something *like* the following:

```
let mut iter = tokens.iter();
while let Some(token) = iter.next() {
    match token {
        Token::Paren(p) => println!("Token::Paren({})", p),
        Token::Number(p) => println!("Token::Number({})", p),
        Token::Name(p) => println!("Token::Name({})", p),
    }
}
```

But obviously the borrow-checker isn't letting me get off so easily.

What's the proper way to do this? Obviously, as you can hopefully tell by the nature of this project, I'm just trying to learn Rust, so any advice would be helpful, even if it's not really related directly to the problem. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your enum owns the strings that are passed in and so destructuring them will attempt to capture them by value (and move it out of the enum).

You can fix this by using `ref p` while destructuring to capture by reference.. stopping the move.

```
match *token {
    Token::Paren(ref p) => println!("Token::Paren({})", p),
    Token::Number(ref p) => println!("Token::Number({})", p),
    Token::Name(ref p) => println!("Token::Name({})", p),
}
```

[Working sample on the Playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=enum%20Token%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Paren(String)%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Number(String)%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Name(String)%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afn%20tokenizer(input%3A%20String)%20-%3E%20Vec%3CToken%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20vec!%5BToken%3A%3ANumber(%2255%22.to_string())%5D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20tokens%20%3D%20tokenizer(%22(add%2044%205)%22.to_owned())%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20iter%20%3D%20tokens.iter()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20while%20let%20Some(token)%20%3D%20iter.next()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20match%20token%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26Token%3A%3AParen(ref%20p)%20%3D%3E%20println!(%22Token%3A%3AParen(%7B%7D)%22%2C%20p)%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26Token%3A%3ANumber(ref%20p)%20%3D%3E%20println!(%22Token%3A%3ANumber(%7B%7D)%22%2C%20p)%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26Token%3A%3AName(ref%20p)%20%3D%3E%20println!(%22Token%3A%3AName(%7B%7D)%22%2C%20p)%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Note that you'll also need to dereference the token because you're using `iter()` which returns references to the tokens in the vector. If you used `into_iter()`, it would transfer ownership out and you can match on non-references.. however your `tokens` variable is now broken as the values are moved.

Comment: My hero! If I may ask another question, because we're doing pattern matching inside the match block, does that cause a move, a copy, or neither? I'm very new to Rust. =)

Comment: It depends on how you capture them. Your original was causing a move (or trying to move it) because you were capturing `p` by value. Using `ref` captures it by reference and therefore doesn't move it. There are other things to consider here but they'll only need explaining as your match blocks become actual blocks of code and have some complexity to them. Other things to consider is whether your type is `Copy` or not.. but again, worry about that later on :)

Comment: It's considered idiomatic to write `match *token { ... }`.

Comment: Thanks @A.B. I have updated the answer. I never know what is idiomatic in that instance because different codebases seem to do different things in that regard.